# How does a super capacitor supply extra energy to an external circuit if the electrolyte doesn't go anywhere

Tags: capacitance

In a super capacitor there is a double layer effect due to charged ions moving into layers. But unlike the electrons in conventional capacitors which line up on a conductive plate and are free to move out into the circuit, I don't see a way for the ions to move out into the circuit.. so how can their presence do anything for capacitance?

Comment: Perhaps the ions near the electrodes allow the electrodes to store more electrons?